# C program to find required number of bits for a given number

Tags: c

I am new at programming and trying to understand the following program.

This program gets the minimum number of bits needed to store an integer as a number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*function declaration
* name      : countBit
* Desc      : to get bits to store an int number
* Parameter : int 
* return    : int 
*/
int countBit(int);
int main()
{
   int num;
   printf("Enter an integer number :");
   scanf("%d",&num);

   printf("Total number of bits required = %d\n",countBit(num));
   return 0;
}

int countBit(int n)
{
   int count=0,i;
   if(n==0) return 0;
   for(i=0; i< 32; i++)
   {    
      if( (1 << i) & n)
         count=i;
   }

   return ++count;
}
```

Can you please explain how the `if( (1 << i) & n)` condition works?

Comment: Read up on bitwise operators.

Comment: Apply the rules of *operator precedence*. `(1 << i)` -- What does that do? What is the value when `i = 0, 1, 2, ...` Then what will *Anding* that value with `n` tell you? Does it tell you whether that bit is set in `n`? If it does, what would you end up with if you counted all the `1-bits` in a number?

Comment: You might get a better response at - https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Kami I don't go there as often as here, but I suspect OP won't get a better response... as I understand it, Code Review is for reviewing code _you've_ written with suggestions for improvements – it's not for explaining how some random piece of code someone has found works.

Comment: @TripeHound Indeed. There even is an authorship close reason which reads "Authorship of code: Since Code Review is a community where programmers improve their skills through peer review, we require that the code be posted by an author or maintainer of the code, that the code be embedded directly, and that the poster know why the code is written the way it is."

Comment: `1 << i` has type `int`; if `int` is 32 bits wide, `1 << 31` has undefined behaviour in general.

Answer (score 2):

To begin you should read up on [Bitwise Operators](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-bitwise-operators--active-11301).

---

```
for(i=0; i< 32; i++)
{   
    // Check if the bit at position i is set to 1
    if( (1 << i) & n)
        count=i;
}
```

In plain english, this is checking what the highest position of all "set" bits is.

> This program gets the minimum number of bits needed to store an integer as a number.

Getting the position of the largest "set" bit will tell us how many bits we need to store that number. If we used a lesser amount of bits, then we would be reducing our maximum possible number to below our desired integer.

Answer (score 1):

"<<" and "&" are bitwise operators, that manipulate a given (usually unsigned integer) variable's bits. You can read more about such operators [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bitwise_operators.htm). In your case,

```
1<<i
```

is the number whose binary representation is 1 followed by i-1 zeroes (and preceded only by zeroes as well). Overall, the check

```
(1<<i)&n
```

evaluates to true if the i-th bit of the variable n is 1, and false otherwise, and therefore the loop finds out what is the leftmost bit which is 1 in the given number.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple if you understand bitwise operators.

**Shift operator:** `<<`is a left shift operator, which shifts a value by designated bits. In C, `x << 1`, will shift `x` by 1-bit.

Lets just consider 8-bit values for now and lets say `x` is `100` in decimal, `0x64` in Hexadecimal numbering system and binary representation of the same would be `0110 0100`
Using the shift operator, lets shift this value 1-bit. So,

```
0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

becomes

```
0  1 1 0 0  1 0 0 0
^                 ^ 
Discarded         Padded
```

as the last (right extreme) bit will be padded with a `0`.

The number becomes, `0xC8`, which is `200` in decimal numbering system, which is double the previous value!

The same goes for a `>>` operator, try it yourselves if you haven't. Result should be the half, except for when you try to `0x01` :-)

As a side note, when you'll grow up and start looking at the way shell/console is used by developers, you'll understand that `>` has a different purpose.

**The `&` operator**: Firstly, `&&` and `&` is different. First one is a logical operator and the latter one is a bitwise operator.

Lets pick a number again, `100`.
In logical `and` operation, the end result is always true or false. For example, `0x64 && 0x64` will result in a true condition, all other combinations will result in a false result.

But, the bitwise `and` operation, is used this way: Is the i<sup>th</sup> bit of 0x64 set? If yes, results in true, else results in false.

The if statement:

```
if( (1 << i) & n)
```

is doing just that. For every iteration of loop, it left shifts `1` by `i` bits, and then checks if the `i`<sup>th</sup> bit of `n` is set, results in true if set, else results in false.

Programmers usually use a macro for this, which makes it more readable.

```
#define CHECK_BIT(value, position)    ((value) & (1 << position))
```